# How to build a filter for a query with multiple dynamic parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've got an array of objects:

```
const myArr = [{
    name: 'a',
    age: 23,
    nationality: 'swedish',
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    age: 23,
    nationality: 'swedish',
  },
  {
    name: 'c',
    age: 25,
    nationality: 'spanish',
  },
];
```

I want to filter with these parameters:

```
const myQuery = {
  name: 'a',
  nationality: 'swedish'
}
```

How would I build a filter for multiple dynamic parameters? I could be looking for 'name', 'age', 'nationality' or something else like 'married'

Comment: Do you have any attempt to show? Did you come up with any basic approach/concept at least?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of myQuery and then I filter myArr with [.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

If I find something I return undefined and object returns as True.

If i don't find object I get boolean variable and object returns as False.

```js
const myArr = [{
    name: 'a',
    age: 23,
    nationality: 'swedish',
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    age: 23,
    nationality: 'swedish',
  },
  {
    name: 'c',
    age: 25,
    nationality: 'spanish',
  },
];

const myQuery = {
  nationality: 'swedish'
}

const filterArray = (arr, query) => {
  return arr.filter(rec => {
    return (typeof Object.keys(query)
      .find(key => rec[key] !== query[key]) === 'undefined') 
  })
}

console.log(filterArray(myArr, {nationality: 'swedish'}))
console.log(filterArray(myArr,{name: 'a',nationality: 'swedish'}))
console.log(filterArray(myArr, {name: 'a',nationality: 'spanish'}))
```